# React SignIn Function with Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I've successfully implemented Google Sign In on my React Web App and would like to extend this to include Sign in with Email and Password. I'm new to React and would love advice as to what I may be doing wrong.

```
export function SignIn() {


  const signIn = async() => {
   console.log("print this to test"); 
    var email = document.getElementById("login").elements.namedItem("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("login").elements.namedItem("password");

    const credential = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("error");
    });

    const { uid, email } = credential.user;
    db.collection('users').doc(uid).set({ email }, { merge: true });

  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={signIn} id="login">
        <label>
          Email
          <input
            name="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password
          <input
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
        </label>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={signIn}>
      Sign In
    </button>
      </form>

  );
}
```

It appears that I'm not able to access these variables correctly. Any idea where I'm going wrong here? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching the value of password field.

**Issue lies here :-**

```
password = document.getElementById("login").elements.namedItem("email"); // <---------
```

**Change it to**

```
password = document.getElementById("login").elements.namedItem("password");
```

Comment: Thanks--embarrassing mistake right there and just updated. However, the "signIn" function doesn't appear to be called onClick. The console message "print this to test" isn't printing after click. Any idea why I'm implementing this incorrectly?

Comment: try removing `onClick={signIn}` from your <button>. Because in react onSubmit is used in the form tag.